# Is there a ASP.NET Core 2 serilog sink for ActiveMq

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, activemq-classic, serilog

I am working on a project and i need a Serilog sink for ActiveMq. I was not able to find this specific sink for ASP.NET Core 2. I need information does this sink already exists or do i need to create my implementation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like it doesn't exist. So you would need to roll something yourself. You can try writing a custom Sink, or use the Periodic Batching Sink and plug in ActiveMQ there.

If you want to try to implement a periodic batching sink you can look to this test for reference:
https://github.com/serilog/serilog-sinks-periodicbatching/blob/dev/test/Serilog.Sinks.PeriodicBatching.Tests/Sinks/PeriodicBatching/PeriodicBatchingSinkTests.cs